# Install Electron app without auto-launching

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm using [Electron-Builder NSIS](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis) to bundle my Electron app. When running the bundle/executable, the app installs AND auto-launches. How do you prevent the app from auto-launching? Basically trying to do a silent install that can be run in a batch from the command line.

Comment: @SarelFoyerlicht I agree with your answer although answering in comments isn't really good so could you delete your comment and post it as a answer instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Electron-Builder NSIS doc(the link you post):

> runAfterFinish = true Boolean - Whether to run the installed
>   application after finish. For assisted installer corresponding
>   checkbox will be removed.

Comment: Jeez, I swear I read through that page about 15 times. Not sure how I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: @sarel-foyerlicht This option only works for .EXE installers and not for .MSI(s). Is there any way to achieve this with .MSI? Because the client DOES NOT want the app to open after .MSI installation.